# How can we replace * with 1/2-1/2 or 1-0 or 0-1 at the end of last line(content) of each and every text file within same directory?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, batch

I have succeeded in several operations of text files with guidance of you friends. Firstly thank you very much for helping me with commands.

Now, I wish to move further in these operations on text file and one of the places I get stuck is I wish I could remove the `*` at the end of last line (of every text file within same directory) with either `1/2-1/2` or `1-0` or `0-1`

This is the text file content:

[image]

> 1. Nh3 d5 2. g3 e5 3. f4 Bxh3 4. Bxh3 exf4*

And 1/2-1/2 would represent a draw which would look like this:
[image]

> 1. Nh3 d5 2. g3 e5 3. f4 Bxh3 4. Bxh3 exf4 1/2-1/2

1-0 means White won and it would be like this:
[image]

> 1. Nh3 d5 2. g3 e5 3. f4 Bxh3 4. Bxh3 exf4 1-0

0-1 would mean Black won and would be like this:
[image]

> 1. Nh3 d5 2. g3 e5 3. f4 Bxh3 4. Bxh3 exf4 0-1

Please ignore the * in the title, i only wish to change the content of the text file.

This I wish to do is because by keeping it from any of `1/2-1/2` or `1-0` or `0-1` I will be able to make the chess engine believe that the game was drawn or lost or won by which side. This would be very useful. I thank you very much for helping me. Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** There are 2000+ files. The reason why I wish to do this is because to find novelties and new lines (never played before) in lesser played variants of the game. This is what I wish to achieve by this operation.

Comment: HI Maverick!  Can you please edit your question and add a little more detail as to what will determine if the text file contains a Win, Lose or Draw?  That might help us help you determine what to replace the `*` with.

Comment: ... a testable sample of input and desired output would be helpful

Comment: Give me just moment, I am editing the question with proper images. Thanks. :) :)

Comment: Actual text is preferred to 'images of text' - just a suggestion for the future.

Comment: Just going to ask, but is there a reason you're trying to write your own Chess engine on Bash, instead of using an existing chess library/engine in other languages, which will solve the problem you're trying to do already?

Comment: No I am not trying to write any engine. I will make these text files to .pgn files and then those .pgn to .bin books. So for each and every ECO code, there would be a book for people to use! The .bin book is a chess engine readable binary file format which contains the moves of the game. So people can force any UCI chess engine to play the opening they want and not what the machine thinks is the best move.

Comment: @Maverick I would say you *probably* should be testing with an actual end-game situation which would lead to either a stalemate or a loss (or a resign).  The PGN as provided is not actually an endgame state - which is probably something you should *consider* since this board as is does not equate to a win, loss, or stalemate situation unless someone is resigning, which suggests to me that what you want to do with inserting or not should *not* be done given this PGN.  (Ran this through an actual engine, and none suggest this is anything that you can claim a checkmate or stalemate at.)

Comment: That is what we know but the chess engine does not know this. I do not want the engine to know the game outcome. I want it to make the initial moves forcefully for a give particular ECO code thinking of the outcome is so and so what I define in these files.

Comment: Please clarify, that you want to replace only the `*` in the last line of the file and not in every line of the file, because proposed solutions replace `*` in all lines, not just the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `gawk`. Install it first:

```
sudo apt install gawk
```

You can replace **the last character** in the line with **a space** followed by **1/2-1/2** like so:

```
for f in *.txt
    do
    gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/.$/," 1/2-1/2")}1' "$f"
    done
```

- Run the code from within the directory containing your `.txt` files.
- You can change what is inside the quotes `" 1/2-1/2"` **notice the leading space after the first quote** to for example `" 1-0"` or `" 0-1"`
- You can change `.$` to `*$` to replace only the last `*` instead of replacing any last character of the line.

Comment: Thank you @Raffa you saved me again. :) I have system booting issue right now. I will use this command once I start my system. Your codes always work. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Technically** you could do this with a call to `sed`...

```
# Note we have to escape the slashes to work with regex / sed here.
REPLACEWITH="1\/2-1\/2"  # or "0-1", or "1-0" depending on your intention
sed -i.orig "s/\*$/${REPLACEWITH}/g" FILENAME
```

... this will find all instances of end of lines with an `*` on them, and replace them with the end of game notation you want to use.  Just make sure if the notation has any `/` characters in it you replace the `/` with a `\/` so that it's properly escaped for `sed` and shell to work with.

Comment: @glennjackman that's there intentionally so you can specify it by REPLACEWITH variable for scripting purposes.  The slashes need to be escaped in this case for the *sed* to recognize it.  And I tested the above and it worked fine.  Delimiters with the escape that I have above worked fine.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake.

Comment: Just change the sed delimiter to something not in the text, like "%", and you don't need to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last character in the file if it is `*` by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305177/how-can-i-remove-the-last-character-of-a-file-in-unix. I changed it a bit to replace it with something else:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    sed -i.bak '$ s/\*$/ 1-0/' $f
done
```

This adds the text only if `*` is at the end of the last line, as you specified in your question. It also makes a copy of original files with `.bak` extension. Remove `.bak`, if you do not want backup files.